# Como criar um módulo no npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

A ideia é conseguir baixar esse módulo pelo `npm install` e conseguir executar esse pacote:

```
npm install nome-do-modulo --save
```

Uma vez baixando poderia ser executado no meu projeto da forma abaixo:

```javascript
nomeDoModulo = require('nome-do-modulo')
```

Comment: ve se [esse link do npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) ajuda.

Answer (score 6):

Os passos a dar são:

```
npm init
```

isso vai criar um `package.json` e vai perguntar-te uma série de coisas sobre o módulo que estás a criar.

Depois costumo fazer tag do código (dar-lhe uma versão), depois de fazer commit com:

```
git tag 1.0.0
```

e para enviar para a npm:

```
npm publish
```

Se ainda não tiveres conta podes criar no site e depois usar `npm login` na linha de comando, ou então fazer diretamente `npm adduser` e depois fazer o `npm publish`.

Como já tenho conta há algum tempo não me lembro das perguntas que fazer mas esses passos devem te levar lá.